# DisplayFormatAttribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, dataformat

I am using MVC3 with Razor and EntityFramework.  To handle event scheduling I have a StartDate, StartTime, EndDate, EndTime using jquery datepicker and timepicker.  I am trying to use the DisplayFormatAttribute in my ViewModel but the Textbox keeps showing the entire DateTime string.

In my viewmodel I have the following properties:

```
    [DisplayFormatAttribute(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime StartDate   { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormatAttribute(DataFormatString = "{0:h:mm tt}")]
    public DateTime StartTime   { get; set; }
```

And my view looks like this:

```
    <div id="event-datetime-range" style="display:inline">
        <span id="event-startdatetime">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { placeholder = "Start Date", id = "event-start-date", @class = "event-datepicker" });

            <span class="event-timerange">at</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartTime, new { placeholder = "Time", id = "event-start-time", @class = "event-timepicker event-timerange" })
        </span>
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `DisplayFormat` attribute is for use with the `Html.DisplayFor()` method and not for use with `Html.TextBoxFor`. I would recommend using a custom `EditorTemplate` to display your date format. Or use jQuery.

Comment: I have a blog post about creating them: http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/10/overriding-displayfor-and-editorfor-to-create-custom-outputs-for-mvc/

Comment: I came across this blog and was considering this method for long term but felt uncomfortable creating an Editor Template since I am only a week into my MVC and Razor experience.  You were right that Html.DisplayFor() worked.  I will eventually use the template but for now, I will try to be flexible and use the jQuery.  Thanks for the reply and for your helpful blog article!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the JQuery date picker use the `dateFormat` option when you create the control.

[jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker)

Also in the date/time format "mm" is minutes where "MM" is months.

You might also want to try `@Html.EditorFor()` instead of `@Html.TextBoxFor()`

Comment: The dateFormat option does not affect the initial value from the model since the view is for new or edit.  Thanks for catching the dateFormatting typo as well.

Comment: Also I had no luck switching to @Html.EditorFor with the FormatAttributes, tho it would seem that in the instance I was running the view, datepicker was not being initiated.  Now that it is, it defaults to clearing out the text box which just means it needs to be set in the jQuery like BuildStarted suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[DisplayFormat(DisplayFormatString={"0:d})]` .